# Is it possible to override Neo4j lock behavior for relationships?

Tags: multithreading, transactions, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

See: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-locking.html
"When creating or deleting a relationship a write lock will be taken on the specific relationship and both its nodes"

Suppose I need to create many relationships within a transaction.  I don't care about locking on the nodes that are connected to those relationships.  In particular, for other concurrent transactions:
1) Updating properties on those nodes does not interfere with my operation
2) Creating or removing *other* relationships to those nodes would not interfere with my operation

The "default locking behavior" generates a huge amount of contention and possibilities for deadlocks in some cases.  For example, I have a set X of 30 nodes, and two transactions are concurrently creating new nodes that have relationships to each node in X.  That requires each transaction to get a write lock on all 30 nodes in X; deadlock is a strong possibility.

The description of the behavior as "default" makes it sound like it is possible to override this behavior.  If so, how can I do this?

(More background: the system normally uses Spring Data Neo4j and Cypher queries to interact with the database.)

Comment: This thread seems to indicate that there is no way to disable the "lock nodes on both ends" behavior when creating or deleting a relationship
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/neo4j/concurrent$20relationships/neo4j/epgmkd4HEcI/1szZGvHDeFwJ
I think using the word "default" in the manual is highly misleading, if there is no option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to override the locking behaviour. Neo4j used to support multiple isolation levels, so it might be that the word "default" is from that time and that the page needs an update.

In Neo4j, you can't delete a node that has relationships. I think that's why it locks the nodes when you create relationships. That it interferes with modifying properties and other relationships is unfortunate.

If you can take liberties with your graph model, you can introduce relation-nodes that the contended nodes can delegate their volatile relationships to. That way you stripe the locks at the cost of a more complicated graph.

Comment: That's too bad.
"In Neo4j, you can't delete a node that has relationships" -- another thorn in my side :S
Perhaps a design flaw, since concurrently adding relationships to the same set of nodes seems like it would be a common use case.

I'm afraid that workaround isn't feasible... it would require sweeping changes to our code and introduce a lot of complexity, since the contended nodes are used in many places.

I'm thinking of introducing an asynchronous process to add these relationships one at a time, serially, each in a separate TX.  This also seems crazy, but I feel my hands are tied.

Comment: @JonathanCrosmer such an asynchronous process could batch things up and add multiple relationships per transaction. This way your throughput should remain good, and you only pay with the added complexity of the asynchronous code. Flat Combining is one way to implement this, and queue + worker thread is another. We _are_ thinking of changing how we do locking, but  changing locking also means changing transaction isolation behaviour, so such changes (if any) won't come until 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I thought about batching relationships, but there's a tradeoff there, since the more we do in a single TX, the more contention and deadlock chances increase.  We'll probably do some benchmarking and see what batch size will work.