# Neo4j - Master nodes and write locks

Tags: graph, neo4j

Current Neo4J documentation states that to create a relationship, both nodes are locked.

Now consider one node be a master node and all other nodes being created are to be related to it. For example, all new "Animal" nodes need to be related to a master "Zoo" node.

So, when a lot of new "Animal" nodes are being created with relationship to existing "Zoo" node, wouldn't all Cypher requests just queue up waiting on the lock ? Because every request needs to lock the "Zoo" node.

I'm observing slow downs when a lot of data is being created on a graph in this manner.

Is there a way to tell Neo4J to *not* lock the nodes for a Cypher CREATE request ? Can some sort of parallel writes be enabled ?

**Update** :

Test Results:

```
Create Zoo nodes: time taken (ms): 2222
Create Animal nodes for separate Zoos: time taken (ms): 2206
Create Animal nodes for same Zoo: time taken (ms): 9015
```

There is a difference of about 7 seconds for just 200 simultaneous queries.

Test Script (using NodeJS Driver, neo4j version 2.2.4, ubuntu linux):

> - NodeJS Driver
> - Neo4j version 2.2.4, community edition
> - Ubuntu Linux

```
var seraph = require('seraph');
var moment = require('moment');
var async = require('async');
var neo4j = seraph({
    "url": "http://localhost:7474",
    "user": "neo4j",
    "pass": "neo4j"
});

var num = 200;

async.series([
    function (cb) {
        // clean
        neo4j.query('MATCH (n:Zoo)-[r:HAS]->(a:Animal) DELETE n,r,a', cb);
    },

    function (cb) {
        // clean
        neo4j.query('MATCH (n:Zoo) DELETE n', cb);
    },

    function (cb) {
        // we create Zoo nodes, each with a num property
        var start = moment();
        var count = 0;
        var abort = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            neo4j.query('CREATE (n:Zoo {obj})', { obj: { num: i } }, function (err, nodes) {
                if (err) {
                    cb(err);
                    abort = true;
                } else {
                    count++;
                    if (count >= num && !abort) {
                        console.log('Create Zoo nodes: time taken (ms): ' + moment().diff(start));
                        cb();
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    },

    function (cb) {
        // we create (Zoo)-[HAS]->(Animal) nodes, each Animal node related with a SEPARATE Zoo node
        var start = moment();
        var count = 0;
        var abort = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            neo4j.query('MATCH (n:Zoo) WHERE n.num = {num} CREATE (n)-[r:HAS]->(a:Animal) RETURN a LIMIT 1', { num: i }, function (err, nodes) {
                if (err) {
                    cb(err);
                    abort = true;
                } else {
                    count++;
                    if (count >= num && !abort) {
                        console.log('Create Animal nodes for separate Zoos: time taken (ms): ' + moment().diff(start));
                        cb();
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    },


    function (cb) {
        // we create (Zoo)-[HAS]->(Animal) nodes, each Animal node related with SAME Zoo node
        var start = moment();
        var count = 0;
        var abort = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            neo4j.query('MATCH (n:Zoo) WHERE n.num = 0 CREATE (n)-[r:HAS]->(a:Animal) RETURN a LIMIT 1', function (err, nodes) {
                if (err) {
                    cb(err);
                    abort = true;
                } else {
                    count++;
                    if (count >= num && !abort) {
                        console.log('Create Animal nodes for same Zoo: time taken (ms): ' + moment().diff(start));
                        cb();
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    }
], function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

    process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: this can maybe help (in fact not, because it says you can't) you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920379/is-it-possible-to-override-neo4j-lock-behavior-for-relationships

Comment: Can you please add your Neo4j version number?

Comment: @Supamiu Updated, Neo4j version: 2.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's mentionned on the question [Is it possible to override Neo4j lock behavior for relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920379/is-it-possible-to-override-neo4j-lock-behavior-for-relationships) :

> It's not possible to override the locking behaviour. Neo4j used to
>   support multiple isolation levels, so it might be that the word
>   "default" is from that time and that the page needs an update.

But you can still have better performances using cypher [Foreach](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-foreach.html) statement if you need to create N relationships to one node. Also, upgrading to Neo4j 2.3 should be good for you, as an upgrade should ever be (don't forget to set `allow_store_upgrade=true`)

Comment: Looks like Neo4J has such locking in implementation, and thus is not performance wise good for free form graphs. The suggested Linked-List like graph design approach is only solution right now.