# Neo4j Cypher, deadlock exception while inserting bulk relationships.

Tags: neo4j, locking, cypher, deadlock, bulkinsert

Due the following use case:

```
(:Product)-[:HAS_PRICE]->(:Price)-[:HAS_CURRENCY]->(:Currency)
```

Having 1000 products and only one (1) currency supported, let’s say `(:Currency {code:'USD'})`.

To insert a Price for each Product, thousand (1000) of relations will be created against the node `(:Currency {code:'USD'}`.

Having 3 working threads receiving the prices and setting them up, the `(:Currency {code:'USD'}` node will be locked for the others two workers while one of the worker creates the edge `-["HAS_CURRENCY]->`.

Implementing a RETRY/BACK-OFF approach avoid some failures, but the RETRY threshold must be higher enough (about 100 in my case) to avoid all deadlocks and setting a long BACK-OFF delay is not worthy.

Chris Vest commented about modifications in locking and transaction isolation behavior in [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920379/is-it-possible-to-override-neo4j-lock-behavior-for-relationships/30932224).

Is there anything we can do to avoid this issue? Any tips around server configuration, data modeling, etc.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there some reason you're modeling :Currency separate from :Price? Unless :Price nodes have other properties besides the numeric price, I'm not quite sure what you're getting out of this model, as :Price and :Currency nodes will need to be paired anyway (I doubt you'll have the same :Price node mapping to two different :Currency nodes, and if currencies map to all related prices for all products, I can't see how the mapping would be useful). Might as well just have a :Price node with properties for the numeric price and the currency code. This change may also remove your deadlock.

Comment: Absolutely @InverseFalcon, there are many reasons. Having (:Currency) as an entity is vital, i.e. currency conversion which involves two kind of currencies.

Comment: That makes sense, you definitely need :Currency nodes to track those conversions (is that implemented in the nodes themselves, or the relationships between the :Currency nodes?). That said, while having relationships between :Price and :Currency may still be helpful, you can still get efficient query performance by looking up the :Currency by the :Price's currencyCode (assuming you add this in) when needed. Not the most graph-oriented way to do this of course, but it may be a fallback if you can't find a good solution to your deadlock problem.